# Infer generic array argument as constant array without using "as const"

Tags: typescript, types, typescript-generics

I am trying to achieve a particular behavior from the type system for an API design. The API accepts an object in which one property is an array of strings and another property should be an element of that array. However I am struggling to achieve this without requiring consumers of the API to explicitly declare the array as readonly using `as const`. It defeats the purpose of type safety when the consumer has to opt into it.

Take a look at this code:

```js
type PaperCompany<Employees extends readonly string[]> = {
  employees: Employees
  topEmployee: Employees[number]
}

function describePaperCompany<Employees extends readonly string[]>(business: PaperCompany<Employees>) {
  // ...
}

describePaperCompany({
  employees: ["michael", "pam", "jim"] as const,
  topEmployee: "stanley" // Error: Type '"stanley"' is not assignable to type '"michael" | "pam" | "jim"'.
})
```

The behavior of the `topEmployee` property is exactly what I want. However, it is possible to pass the array without the `as const` directive which causes the type of `topEmployee` to be inferred as `string` instead of `"michael" | "pam" | "jim"`.

Let's assume the implementation of my `describePaperCompany` API requires `topEmployee` to be one of the elements of `employees`, otherwise it will fail. I want the type checker to enforce this, but requiring the `as const` part means every caller of the API has to sign up for the enforcement. They can simply omit `as const` and won't receive any type errors.

As you can see I have already included the `readonly` keyword in the type signatures, but the type checker still allows non-readonly types to be passed as arguments. Is there anything I can do to achieve the same behavior without `as const`?

Comment: TS5.0 will include [`const` type parameters](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/typescript/announcing-typescript-5-0-beta/#const-type-parameters) at which time you can get the desired behavior [like this](https://tsplay.dev/wE4QZW).  But is there some reason you care about `readonly` or the order of the tuple?  I'd think you really just care about the string literals and you could do [this](https://tsplay.dev/m0bpRw).  Does either or both of these fully address your question? If so I could write up an answer; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: Alternatively, you can use a utility type like [this](https://tsplay.dev/Nd2nkW). ts-toolbelt has a different implementation, I imagine it handles a few edge-cases.

Comment: @jcalz That is an absolutely perfect answer. Your solution works perfectly and feels correct. And yes, that new feature in TS 5.0 addresses this exact use case. Thank you!

Comment: @geoffrey While less terse, your solution is also great. I think there are ideas here that are even more widely applicable. Will add this to my bag of tricks.